# How retrive Process Privilege (windows drivers)?

Tags: c, wdm, filter-driver

I have  an object of IRP and EPROCESS in my driver 
i want to know how can i retrieve process privilege (like **normal** or **Administrator** or **SYSTEM**) from these structures ?

```
 KPROCESSOR_MODE ProcessRequestorMode = pIrp->RequestorMode;
        UNICODE_STRING PRM;
        if (ProcessRequestorMode == KernelMode)
            status = RtlInitUnicodeStringEx(&PRM, L"Kernel-Mode");
        else
        {
            status = RtlInitUnicodeStringEx(&PRM, L"User-Mode");
            //////////////////////////TODO////////////////////
            //retrieving process previlage
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        DBGMSG1("Processor Mode : %wZ   ", PRM);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            DBGMSG0("Can not convert RequestorMode to UNICODE_STRING\n");
            ASSERT(FALSE);
            return status;
        }
```

Comment: What driver? What language? Is this actually a programming question?

Comment: it's a filter driver (WDM driver) in C programming language and i use WDK in visual studio 2015

Comment: So [edit] your post to add such relevant tags, and ideally show some of the code you're already using with an explanation of where you want to add the new code to retrieve the privilege info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is stored in the process token.
You can get that using [PsReferencePrimaryToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-psreferenceprimarytoken)
If the process is impersonating you can use PsReferenceImpersonationToken instead.
After that you simply query the token for the *TokenUser* using [ZwQueryInformationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationtoken).

Good luck,
Gabriel